# Square Root Radical Sign

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to type a radical of a square root equation as `\sqrt{}` with any number inside the bracket? I looked up how to do it but there were only these answers with advanced LaTeX that I don't understand. Any help someone?

Comment: You can just use `\surd`. See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Yes, just make sure you are in math mode: example `$\sqrt{}$`, or if you want the horizontal line `$\sqrt{\hphantom{99}}$`, where the `widthof{99}` determines how wide it is. If you actually have a number just use `$\sqrt{<num>}$`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want a square root sign with nothing under it, or an nth root sign (like cube root, fourth root, etc.)? None of these require "advanced LaTeX" (first is `\surd`, second is `\sqrt[n]{x}`), so maybe you want something else?

Answer (score 57):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change this line to \documentclass{article} or whatever you want.

\begin{document}
\noindent
The square root of 100 is $\sqrt{100}=10$. 
\\
But the cubic root of 64 is $\sqrt[3]{64}=4$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `\sqrt{.........}` and put what ever numbers between the brackets.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing the `$` and `$` for math mode. Also, it might be helpful to make a complete minimal working example so you can show the result in your answer.